# How to avoid alias shadowing in nested fields with non-unique names?

Tags: google-bigquery

Given the following table:

[image: 4f0lAb9]

I'd like to rename `fred` to `freddy`.

For this, I've written the following code:

```sql
WITH foo AS (
    SELECT
    1 corge,
    STRUCT(
        [STRUCT(
            2 AS bar,
            3 AS fred)
        ] AS qux,
        4 AS plugh
    ) bar
)

SELECT
    corge as corge,
    (SELECT AS STRUCT ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT
            bar.qux.bar as bar,
            bar.qux.fred as freddy
        FROM
            foo.bar.qux)
        as qux)
    as bar,
    plugh as plugh
FROM
    foo
```

But it results in the following error:

```
Cannot access field qux on a value with type INT64 at [17:17]
```

It seems like the inner `bar` is shadowing the outer `bar`. How can I avoid this and make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
WITH foo AS (
    SELECT
    1 corge,
    STRUCT(
        [STRUCT(2 AS bar, 3 AS fred), (22, 32)] AS qux,
        4 AS plugh
    ) bar
)
SELECT
    corge as corge,
    (SELECT AS STRUCT 
        ARRAY(SELECT STRUCT(bar, fred as freddy) FROM unnest(bar.qux)) AS qux,
        bar.plugh) AS bar
FROM foo
```

Answer (score 2):

How about to avoid all of those UNNESTs and rebuilding the arrays and rather simply force new names as it is in below example

```
WITH foo AS (
    SELECT
    1 corge,
    STRUCT(
        [STRUCT(
            2 AS bar,
            3 AS fred)
        ] AS qux,
        4 AS plugh
    ) bar
), foo_with_new_names AS (
    SELECT
    -1 corge,
    STRUCT(
        [STRUCT(
            2 AS bar,
            3 AS freddy)
        ] AS qux,
        4 AS plugh
    ) bar
)
select * from foo_with_new_names where false 
union all select * from foo
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure I understand correctly. The actual table, represented by `foo` in my minimal example, does already exist (and is quite large). I can't just recreate its content like this if that is what you mean.

Comment: you need "recreate" just **one row**! in most cases this is less "pain" then anyway recreating new schema via code! that's for sure. Note, this is just alternative option for you! :o)

Comment: Ah, now I understand, Interesting! That's why you used to `-1` in `foo_with_new_names`, to show that the schema from `foo_with_new_names` is used but the data from `foo`. That's very clever! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69850015/1866775) given by [Sergey Geron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13473525), here is a version that additionally preserves the order of the elements in the `qux` array:

```sql
WITH foo AS (
    SELECT
    1 corge,
    STRUCT(
        [STRUCT(
            2 AS bar,
            3 AS fred)
        ] AS qux,
        4 AS plugh
    ) bar
)

SELECT
    corge AS corge,
    (SELECT AS STRUCT ARRAY(
        SELECT STRUCT(
            bar AS bar,
            fred AS freddy)
        FROM
            UNNEST(bar.qux)
        WITH OFFSET AS bar_qux_offset ORDER BY bar_qux_offset)
        AS qux,
        bar.plugh)
    AS bar
FROM
    foo
```